# Symfony creates wrong SQL when I adding sorting with pagination

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.8

If I use `getLatestProducts()` function from my `ProductRepository` class, I have an error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT DISTINCT id_0 FROM (
    SELECT p0_.id AS id_0, p0_.title AS title_1, p0_.type AS type_2, p0_.status AS status_3, p0_.price AS price_4, p0_.price_sale AS price_sale_5, p0_.created AS created_6, p0_.updated AS updated_7, p0_.number_orders AS number_orders_8, p0_.quantity AS quantity_9, p0_.image_name AS image_name_10, p0_.serial AS serial_11
    FROM product p0_) dctrn_result
    ORDER BY type_2 DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0':

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
    3065 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list,
    references column 'dctrn_result.type_2' which is not in SELECT list;
    this is incompatible with DISTINCT
```

If I delete string `->orderBy('p.type', 'DESC')` from `getLatestProducts` function, pagination works! What have I done wrong?

```
public function getLatestProducts($currentPage = 1, $limit = 5)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->orderBy('p.type', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery();

    $paginator = $this->paginate($qb, $currentPage, $limit);

    return $paginator;

}

public function paginate($dql, $page = 1, $limit = 5)
{
    $paginator = new Paginator($dql);

    $paginator->getQuery()
        ->setFirstResult($limit * ($page - 1)) // Offset
        ->setMaxResults($limit); // Limit

    return $paginator;
}
```

I know, that I can use [KnpPaginatorBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle), but I'd like to repair this. And if I add some `where` parameters to query in `getLatestProducts` function, it worked...

Answer (score 0):

As the *General Error* suggests, try add to `createQueryBuilder()`:

```
->select('p.id, p.type')
```

Comment: $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select('p.id, p.type')
            ->addOrderBy('p.serial', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery();   dont work for me